# Testing properties with private setters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, encapsulation, access-modifiers

Currently in a part of my project a domain object like below exists:

```
public class Address
{
    public virtual string HouseName { get; set; }

    public virtual string HouseNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual string RoadName { get; set; }

    public virtual string Postcode { get; set; }

    public virtual string District { get; private set; }
}
```

The District property is a calculated column in the database. Due to the requirements of the data access provider (Entity Framework) a private set is required. This is fine in normal program flow as the District never needs to be set, due to it being updated when an Address record is saved/updated in the database

A method that I want to test looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<House> GetHousesWithinSameDistrict (int addressId)
{
    var addressToMatch = _addressRepository
      .FirstOrDefault(address => address.Id == addressId)

    return _houseRepository
      .Where(house => house.Address.District == addressToMatch.District)
}
```

This is causing me problems when I try to set up the addressToMatch variable, as I am unable to set the District property and as such I cannot write a test to check correct matching addresses are returned.

How should I go about setting up an Address object for this test?

Comment: Maybe, `protected internal` + `assembly:InternalsVisibleTo`?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Related, but certainly no duplicate IMHO.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Not at all a duplicate of that.

Comment: Making it `protected set` and creating a subclass with a setter method (as a private class of the testfixture) is a (not very pretty but pragmatic) workaround.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood this question. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Without seeing your test it's hard to give advice, but you *could* use a Mock of the address you need to Match, and use SetupGet to return the value you want, You *could* set the value that you need to using reflection, or if you're using MS testing framework you could use PrivateObject to set the value.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244100.aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works out of the box if you're using Moq (which the question is tagged with, so I assume you are):

```
var mockAddress = new Mock<Address>();
mockAddress.SetupGet(p => p.District).Returns("Whatever you want to match");
```

So a more complete example is:

```
var mockAddress = new Mock<Address>();
mockAddress.SetupGet(p => p.Id).Returns(42);
mockAddress.SetupGet(p => p.District).Returns("What you want to match");

var mockAddressRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Address>>();
var addresses = new List<Address> { mockAddress.Object };
mockAddressRepository.Setup(p => p.GetEnumerator()).Returns(addresses.GetEnumerator());

var addressToMatch = mockAddressRepository.Object.FirstOrDefault(address => address.Id == 42);
Console.WriteLine(addressToMatch.District);
```

This outputs the expected value:

```
What you want to match
```

Comment: This answer is all kinds of awesome. I was about to make my property internal and set InternalsVisibleTo. Or I was going to use PrivateObject. This answer is so easy and nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First, a wild guess: maybe a combination of declaring your `District` propery as `protected internal` plus adding an `assembly:InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to your "domain" assembly so that `Distinct` could be set from your tests.

```
class Address
{
    public virtual string District { get; protected internal set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add an internal constructor to your `Address` class, which would set the value of the `District` property. And again, annotate your "domain" assembly with `assembly:InternalsVisibleTo`.

Comment: Is there some alternative to using InternalsVisibleTo? It makes my code a little confusing and not clear (I am practicing ddd, so all of the properties' set in my classes are private), I would really appreciate if you could tell me some more elegant solution for this. Thanks